# Build Spacing for Error Text into Input Group

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to build in spacing for error text on my form input group component. The goal is to avoid displacing any elements on my forms when the error text is shown.

In the example below, there *should* be 25 pixels of empty space between the password input and "I forgot my password" such that when the input is invalid, the error text can be displayed without moving the elements that were already visible on the page.

[image: There should be spacing below the password input so that the "field required" text doesn't make the "I forgot my password" text move when it appears]

My solution using negative margins *did* seem to work for some reason before I started using the bootstrap 4 grid system.

```
    <b-form-group v-bind="$attrs" class="tsny_input-group">
      <b-input
        v-bind="$attrs"
        v-model="innerValue"
        class="tsny_input"
        :invalid="invalid"
      />
      <div class="tsny_field_error-text">
        {{ errors[0] }}
      </div>
    </b-form-group>
```

```
  .tsny_input-group {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }

  .tsny_field_error-text {
    font-family: "expo-sans-pro", sans-serif;
    color: #FF8787;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `min-height` to preserve the space when there is no text?

Comment: place error in `p` tag and then `<p> {{ errors[0] || ' ' }} </p>`

Comment: @DavidWeldon that solved it. I was able to get rid of the margins too, which makes things a lot cleaner. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I'm glad that worked. Negative margins are a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using David Weldon's min-height suggestion. I was able to get rid of my margins, my final CSS is as follows:

```
  .tsny_field_error-text {
    font-family: "expo-sans-pro", sans-serif;
    color: #FF8787;
    min-height: 25px;
  }
```